# Unable to access any folder (including HOME)

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, directory, home-directory

I have recently(couple of days ago) installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside Windows 10. Everything appeared working but today when I logged into Ubuntu, I am unable to access any folder (including HOME). When I click on the Files icon, there is a white circle rotating and nothing happens. How to get a permanent fix to this?

**edit**:
When I run Nautilus in the terminal, I get this [information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4swc1.png).

**edit2:**
Now, I have restarted Ubuntu and I am getting the same output when I type **nautilus** in terminal. However, to my surprise, now I am able to access folders(including Home) from **Files** icon.

Comment: Please open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t or super+t) and type `nautilus`, is your filemanager opening?

Comment: No; edited the question with the obtained information from the terminal.

Comment: Is Network Manager operating?

Comment: @Graham: How to verify this? Can you provide any  commands?

Comment: In terminal type ifconfig which should tell you if eth0 or eth1 link is up eg: Link  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST

Comment: You can also look at Network in System Settings which should tell you if you are connected to the network.

Answer (score 0):

After your edit2, that certainly seems like a network manager missing problem which I too have experienced since updating to 16.04LTS. When this occurs, I also find that by rebooting, it magically re-sets itself and works fine for quite a period of time before unexpectedly happening again. I notice it from the missing up/down arrow keys icon on the top bar of the screen which indicates network manager is not functioning.

An alternate to rebooting is to open a terminal and type:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up

sudo dhclient eth0
```

This should reset the network manager eth0 link to up for that session (at least) but may need to be repeated (or the system rebooted as discussed above) if it happens again.

I'm sure it won't be too long before some kindly soul comes along with a permanent fix for it.